# In svg using d3 v4 bubble chart, use z-index property to show circle topup

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I am using d3.v4 bubble chart with svg canvas. I want to use z-index property on mouseover the bubble, I am using below code:

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {  
  return this.each(function(){
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};
d3.selection.prototype.moveToBack = function() {  
    return this.each(function() { 
        var firstChild = this.parentNode.firstChild; 
        if (firstChild) { 
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, firstChild); 
        } 
    });
};
```

Below code in ngOnIt:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).moveToFront();
})
```

Help me out, Guys!
Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a fiddle etc where you can link to?

Comment: @ibowankenobi, sorry I am not using fiddle etc.

Comment: Then without seeing the example, my guess is that you are trying to bring element to front with mouseover, however it will never trigger because you cannot mouseover it, there are other elements on it. Then in this case, add a mousemove handler to your main svg, and check with intervals whether you are sufficiently close to x and y attiributes of your object by either doing getAttribute or elem.x.baseVal etc. A better solution would be to look up quadtrees.